# Sorting HTML table returns the error, "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')"

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to build a function to sort selected columns in an HTML table. This is what I have come up with:

```
cPrev = -1;
function sortBy(c){
    rows = document.getElementById("table-sort").rows.length;
    cols = document.getElementById("table-sort").rows[0].cells.length;
    arrTable = [...Array(rows)].map(e => Array(cols));
    for(let rw = 0; rw < rows; rw++){
        for(let cl = 0; cl < cols; cl++){
            arrTable[rw][cl] = document.getElementById("table-sort").rows[rw].cells[cl].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    th = arrTable.shift();
    if (c!== cPrev){
        arrTable.sort(
            function (a,b){
                if(a[c] === b[c]){
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return (a[c] < b[c]) ? -1: 1;
                }
            }
        )
    } else {
        arrTable.reverse();
    }
    cPrev = c;
    arrTable.unshift(th);
    for(let rw=0; rw < rows; rw++){
        for(let cl=0; c < cols; cl++){
            document.getElementById("table-sort").rows[rw].cells[cl].innerHTML = arrTable[rw][cl];
        }
    }
}
```

This is my HTML table:

```
<table id="table-sort">
    <tbody id="tBody">
        <tr>
            <th onClick="sortBy(0)">Transaction Date</th>
            <th onClick="sortBy(1)">Merchant</th>
            <th onClick="sortBy(2)">Amount</th>
            <th onClick="sortBy(3)">Currency</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-th="Transaction Date">
            </td>
            <td data-th="Merchant">
            </td>
            <td data-th="Amount">
            </td>
            <td data-th="Currency">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a portion of the function I use to populate the table initially:

```
    const res = JSON.parse(response)["transactionList"]
    for(var i = 0; i < res?.length; i++) {
        var row = $(
            "<tr><td>"
            + res[i].inserted
            + "</td><td>"
            + res[i].merchant
            +"</td><td>"
            + res[i].amount/100
            +"</td><td>"
            + res[i].currency
            +"</td></tr>"
            );
        $('#tBody').append(row);
    }
```

The problem is, I am getting this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')
```

How can I resolve this issue and my sort function working?

Comment: Are you possibly including the script or calling the method before the DOM is completely ready?

Comment: You are trying to loop over more cells than there actually are. `for(let cl=0; c < cols; cl++)` - you used the wrong variable in your condition, `c < cols` - that `c` needs to be your loop counter variable, `cl`.

Comment: Also, on your second groupings of for-loops.  Did you mean to write: ```c < cols``` as oppossed to ```cl < cols```??

Comment: @DanOrlovsky I believe I am triggering the sort function when the table is populated